# Search JSON using a keyword in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Today I need some help with a `search` command!

I want to grab a name and `waifuURL` when someone specifies a specific keyword (the waifus name).
This is how my `json` is formatted:

```
{
    "waifuID": {
        "1": {
            "names": "Megumin",
            "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b89361-xH1t0q5WeAN8.png",
            "claims": "#1"
        },
        "2": {
            "names": "Mai Sakurajima",
            "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b127222-IY5iDRuXLY8i.png",
            "claims": "#2"
        },
        "3": {
            "names": "Zero Two",
            "img_url": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/character/large/b124381-pkTKi6HHNuVR.png",
            "claims": "#3"
        }
}
}
```

I want to be able to do `!search <waifuname>` and it would give the `img_url` and the name of the waifu from the `json`.

For example:

Input: `!search Zero Two`

Response:

`Zero Two`

`<img_url>`

(These responses will be put in an embed)

That's the gist of it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to find the object in question. From there, you'll be able to access it's `img_url` property, `claims` property, etc.

```js
// returns corresponding object
Object.values(obj.waifuID)
  .find(value => value.names === "Zero Two"))
```

```js
// getting img_url
console.log(Object.values(obj.waifuID)
  .find(value => value.names === "Zero Two").img_url)
```

Comment: How would I log this in my console?

Comment: I found a much simpler answer and edited my answer accordingly, along with how to log it.

Comment: Hmmm, I seem to be getting an error that obj is not defined.

Comment: Nevermind, I just let obj = my JSON file and it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: Last thing, how could I make it so even if I give lower case, it'll still register?
(Only the first characters on every space)

Comment: You can use `.find(value => value.names.toLowerCase() === <name>.toLowerCase())`

Comment: `<name>` is a placeholder for whatever variable you use to represent the name given from the command.

Comment: Glad I could help :)